# Is it possible to compare strings in a list C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I want to be able to take a list and compare the strings in the list. I CAN NOT FIGURE IT OUT... Is using a list the best way or should I be using an array? How do I compare strings and count the number of times they show up in a list? I swear I've tried everything and I've googled a bit and I can't find a way to count every time a string is repeated in a list...

```
     private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         string currentstring;
         int currentindex;
         int nextindex;
         for (currentindex = 0; currentindex < linestocompare.Count; currentindex++)
         {
             currentstring = linestocompare.ElementAt(currentindex);
             nextindex = currentindex + 1;
             //foreach (string lines in linestocompare)
            // {
                 string nextstring = linestocompare.ElementAt(nextindex);
                      if(currentstring.Equals(nextstring))
                 {
                     endresult.Items.Add(currentstring);
                     
                 }
             else
             {
                
             }
                 
            // }
             //endresult.Items.Add(currentstring);
              }***

          }
```

Comment: Your code attempts to find consecutive equals strings. What if two strings are equal but not consecutive in the list? Do you wish to count them?

Comment: "take a list and compare the strings in the list" - compare them to _what_? Eachother? All of them? Or only neighbors in the list?